# NFC intent on Android for Work

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-for-work

I've created a very basic app that has an intent for external NDEF type as shown below.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
        android:host="ext"
        android:pathPrefix="/com.example:externalType"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The activity the above is nested in is the main activity for the app and is just a vanilla blank activity.

All works fine on the standard user side however if I side load the app on to the Work Profile the intent never reaches the app and the "New tag collected" screen is shown.

The Android documentation states that the Profile administrator can control which intents are sent across from the user to the work profile however I can find no such settings within the BlackBerry Enterprise Server 12 (our MDM) console or the Android for Work console.

http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html#prevent_failed_intents